# Use of specifying size while dynamically allocating memory

Tags: c++, memory-management, char, delete-operator

I am trying to understand what is exact use of specifying size while dynamically allocating memory using new keyword and what role does it play when that memory is being freed.

```
 char* c = new char; // Not specifying size here
 c[0] = 'h';
 c[1] = 'i';
 c[2] = '\0';
 delete c;        

 char* d = new char[3];
 d[0] = 'h';
 d[1] = 'i';
 d[2] = '\0';
 delete[] d;
```

I know that in first example I am accessing wrong portion of memory, and it is also evident that by calling delete, it would not free up the all allocated memory, but I am trying to understand that what else could go wrong in this scenario, while calling delete.

And from my understanding, in order to keep track of memory being allocated and for properly freeing it up whenever required, size specification is required. Please provide some information on this part.

Comment: `char* c = new char;` allocates the space for 1 character. Trying to access more than that is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying the size allocates an array. If your type is `int[3]` it will allocate space for 3 `int`'s. If the type is just `int`, it will allocate only enough memory for 1 `int`.

> And from my understanding, in order to keep track of memory being allocated and for properly freeing it up whenever required, size specification is required. Please provide some information on this part.

You need to keep track of how much memory you allocated so you don't go out of bounds. As for freeing memory, `delete` and `delete[]` just work. They handle freeing the correct amount of memory reguardless of if you're tracking it in the program.

Answer (score 3):

The first version of the code allocates space for one character, this is perfectly valid, you can allocate for a single thing with `new` or an array of things with `new[]`. The trouble is you then you go and *stomp all over memory you don't own*, which is undefined behaviour.

Nothing goes wrong when you call `delete`, you're deleting a valid, previously allocated pointer. What can go wrong is if you're mutating memory you don't own.

In the second case you allocate for 3 characters and the manipulations are valid.

Note that in C++ you should be using either `std::string` for string data, or `std::vector` for variable length or `std::array` for fixed length allocations.

Answer (score 1):

"what else could go wrong in this scenario"

Well, it's Undefined Behavior. That means all guarantees are gone - for good. Harddisk formatted? Everything could go wrong, so that too.

Just use `std::string`. It saves harddisks.

Comment: There's OS-level protections from formatting hard disks, but as for leaving the fridge door open after eating all the cheese? No such assurances.